# Where to Install Applications when using Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, command-line

I use the command line a lot to download and install applications. I've always downloaded into the `/tmp` directory then installed to another directory.

But where is the place to install such applications? For example, I was just downloading *MongoDB* (a database application similar to *MySQL*).
And I had no idea where to put it.

Where should such applications be installed on Mac?
Whats the conventional way?

Comment: Also, you could use a package manager like homebrew - http://brew.sh and it has one command install of mongodb and handles where to store things for you systematically.

Answer (score 0):

As OS X is a UNIX OS at its core you can usually use the installers that come with the open source tools you've mentioned.

Quite often there's some way to install them, usually there's 3 steps to configure, compile, and install the tools.

For stuff like databases and other UNIX tools they might need stuff in a number of places.

In contrast to that a typical Mac application will be just one self-contained application bundle that's supposed to go in to your /Applications folder.

Though it can as well run from your Desktop, Downloads folder, etc. ...

Comment: The installation instructions for MongoDB are here (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). It says to optionally move the extracted archive to another folder (which I will need to do anyway because it's currently in the `/tmp` folder). But where would be the conventional place to put it? There is no package installer for MongoDB so I'm having to do it via the terminal.